# iMac doesn't recognize my MacBook Pro when connecting via mini DisplayPort

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, displayport

I use my iMac as an external monitor for my MacBook Pro via mini DisplayPort. But, sometimes, it fails. The iMac went black for some seconds when I plugged the cable in but it went back into the normal mode instead of displaying the MacBook Pro's screen. Today I  couldn't get it to work any way. I restarted the iMac, removed and reinserted the cable, but nothing helps.

Comment: To my knowledge, mini-DVI iMacs aren't capable of displaying other computers' screens. Are you sure it's [mini-DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kobushi-mini-dvi.jpg), not [mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mini_DisplayPort_on_Apple_MacBook.jpg) or Thunderbolt? (The links are to pictures to compare them; Thunderbolt looks just like mini DisplayPort.)

Comment: You're right its mini DisplayPort. I'll change it in my question.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the question bumps it up to the top of the front page, so hopefully someone who uses the remote display feature of their iMac will notice the question and answer it.